# DDD many-to-many relationship on single entity

Tags: domain-driven-design, database-design

To provide a bit of context, the system I'm working on is a football database. A **Squad** has a collection of **Rival**s. Arsenal (Squad) has Tottenham and Chelsea as rivals, where Chelsea has Tottenham and Leeds United as rivals. These rivals are also Squads.

I'm thinking 'Rival' should probably be a value object, but I'm not exactly sure how to model this in my database. Reading [this article by Udi Dahan](http://udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/), I'm trying to avoid many-to-many relationships as much as I can.

How should I go about modelling this relationship in my domain and what would it look like in my database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm thinking 'Rival' should probably be a value object, but I'm not exactly sure how to model this in my database.

The database schema doesn't change very much.  You are still going to have a table that documents the relationship between two squads.  It might be a table dedicated to rivalries, or it might be a more generic relationship table, or it might be two tables, one that defines the relationship, and another that defines the participants in that relationship.

What Udi is pointing out is that the relations should not be managed as a *set*: changing Arsenal's relationship with Tottenham should be independent of changing Arsenal's relationship with Chelsea.  In other words, we should be forgiving of partial failure.

Once you agree that support for partial failure is the Right Thing, then you are looking at multiple transactions.  And once you have multiple transactions *anyway*, you get to look into the model with fresh eyes, and think more deeply about where the authority for a relationship resides.

(Note: authority is a really important concept -- but it can feel vague in many cases because the actual authority isn't the model, but instead the Real World, or some person in the Real World.)

One way of modeling that would be to make the Rivalry itself an "aggregate", with values that identify each squad as part of its data.  Rivalry is, after all, a "thing" that you can talk about, with a life cycle of its own (when did the rivalry start? when did it stop?), so it's reasonable to think about it as its own entity, and it may make sense as its own aggregate as well.